# "Booting in insecure mode" - how to reset MOK Management

Tags: boot, bootloader, storage, secure-boot

No matter how much I recreate the partition layout (gpt) and install another distribution on it, data from the MOK management/shim for Secure Boot is always there. The only storage device I have is a 32 GB eMMC.

Is it possible that Secure Boot configuration is being stored in another chip? I am looking for a BIOS update to reset everything that could be there. I keep getting a message ("booting in insecure mode...") with a delay of 2 seconds, no matter if I disable or enable Secure Boot.

**Can I reset those settings to default, so that no message will appear on boot?**

I use Ubuntu MATE. The microcode updates are proprietary, that's why I tried to use MOK Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run `sudo mokutil --disable-verification` in order to stop the message from appearing at boot. It makes total sense now.